# How to return 2 values in filter function in an angular app or how to improve this code

Tags: angular

I have a question about how to set 2 values in a anuglar filter function at one time.

my code as follow:

```
let bookedServiceData
let unbookedServiceData

I got value allData, this is array object

allData = [{
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
    service: {
      id: "123"
      name: "name1"
 
    },

    {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
    service: {
      id: "222"
      name: "name2"

    } ,
    

  ...

}]

so I just want to get the object with service id= 123 and the other object without service with serviceid 123.

I have 2 mehtodes.

private getServiceWithId123(): void {
    
      this.bookedServiceData = this. allData?.filter((value) => {
        return value.service?.id === "123";
      });
    
  }
```

and I have the other function which gets all services without serviceId 123

```
private getServiceWithId123(): void {

      this.unbookedServiceData = this. allData?.filter((value) => {
        return value.service?.id !== "123";
      });

  }
```

how can I combine this 2 mehtod in the best way?

any solution?

Comment: Isn't that a conflict when you try to filter with `id==='123'` and `id!=='123'` at the same time?

Comment: sorry I have edited my qustion

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the conditions in the same method:

```
    private getServices(): void {
    if (this.allData) {
        this.bookedServiceData = [];
        this.unbookedServiceData = [];
        this.allData.forEach(value => {
            if (value.service) {
                if (value.service == '123') {
                    this.bookedServiceData.push(value);
                }
                else {
                    this.unbookedServiceData.push(value);
                }
            }
        })
    }
    }
```

value.service is for the  only values with a valid service, you can remove it if you need all services

Comment: But I want to get these 2 values bookedServiceData and unbookedServiceData

Comment: This return all the values that have a truthy `service` value since `(value.service.id !== "123" || value.service.id == "123")` will always be `true`

Comment: @user1938143 the filter method returns only an array, you can use 2 filters methods (in 2 lines) or a for/foreach cycle with an if/else condition

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this

```
    private getServiceWithId123(): void {
      this.bookedServiceData = this.allData?.map((value) => {
       If(value.service?.id === "123")
            return value.service.id
      });
     this.UnbookedServiceData = this.allData?.map((value) => {
        If(value.service?.id !== "123")
           return value.service.id
      });
  }
```

i guess filtering will be saved bookedServiceData filter will have value.service?.id === "123"
and UnbookedServiceData filter will have value.service?.id !== "123"

Comment: But I need thers 2 values bookedServiceData and unbookedServiceData seperately.

Comment: i have changed accordingly please check this will work fine for your requirement

Comment: Using map at this place will just give out a array of true false value. Filter is the right solution for filtering out, whereas MAP is used to map an array to a different one.
@Vignesh
The output for your code would be something like this, [true, false, false, ....]

And to answer the author's question, If you would want to use filter then it's already in optimal way and there's not way to get two different array.
Other option would be to use basic for loop and to push elements conditionally into two different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it as separate variables, the closest thing you can do to use `Array.reduce()` to create an object like `{booked: [], unbooked: []}`

```js
const allData = [{
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    service: {
      id: "123",
      name: "name1"

    }
  },

  {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    service: {
      id: "222",
      name: "name2"

    }
  }
]

const filteredData = allData.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  cur.service.id === '123' ? acc.booked.push(cur) : acc.unbooked.push(cur);
  return acc;

}, {
  booked: [],
  unbooked: []
});

console.log(filteredData);
```